# got error by js when using ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I want to get the result via ajax in jquery but I get `unexpected identifier`.
when the modal is loaded the script will be executed.
this is my code:

```
        $('#extend').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
    $('#ext_btn').on('click',function(){
        var param={
            session:<?php  echo $_SESSION['session'] ;?>,
            request:'extendItem',
            item_id: <?php echo $item_id ; ?>,
            user_id: <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>,
            request:'extendItem',
            expiration_date:$('#ext_date').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:'index.php',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data:param,
            type:'POST',
            success: function(e){
                alert(JSON.stringify(e));
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error appeared!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: error outputs are more specific than that...should tell you where. Inspect actual source since it appears you haven't quoted the php output shown properly

Comment: Please paste full error message.

Answer (score 0):

session:"php contact "

Try with single or double quotes when passing php values in ajax post